# Amazon Redshift VACUUM runs per schema or per database?

Tags: amazon-redshift, vacuum

Does `VACUUM;` with no other arguments run per database or per current schema on amazon redshift?

The reason I am asking this is because when VACUUM completes on one schema and I change the default schema, and run it again, it takes a whole hour to complete.

Comment: Which user are you using to run VACUUM?

Comment: a user that has been given to me by the admins... it has privileges an all schemas

Comment: It must be a super user to permfrom it.

Answer (score 2):

VACUUM with no arguments runs on the entire database. See the [Amazon Redshift VACUUM doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_VACUUM_command.html): "Reclaims space and resorts rows in either a specified table or all tables in the current database.".